# Getting error trying to run script with SQLTools

Tags: sqltools

I tryed to use the *SqlTools* extansion for VSCorde and wanted to run the script with it and gives me this erros (I'm using github codespaces)

````
[1674681282366] INFO  (ext): EXECUTING COMMAND => sqltools.getConnections
[1674681282367] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/GetConnectionsRequest
[1674681282368] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/GetConnectionsRequest
[1674681282369] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/GetConnectionsRequest
[1674681284190] INFO  (ext): EXECUTING COMMAND => sqltools.getConnections
[1674681284191] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/GetConnectionsRequest
[1674681284191] INFO  (ls): REQUEST RECEIVED => connection/ConnectRequest
[1674681284192] INFO  (ls): Connection instance created for panel.
    ns: "conn-manager"
[1674681284193] ERROR (ls): {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"MySQL","driverOptions":{"mysqlOptions":{"authProtocol":"default"}}},"name":"Error"}
    ns: "conn"
[1674681284193] ERROR (ls): Connecting error: {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"MySQL","driverOptions":{"mysqlOptions":{"authProtocol":"default"}}},"name":"Error"}
    ns: "conn-manager"
[1674681284193] ERROR (ls): Open connection error
    ns: "conn-manager"
[1674681284194] ERROR (ext): ERROR: Error fetching records. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306, {"code":-1,"data":{"driver":"MySQL","driverOptions":{"mysqlOptions":{"authProtocol":"default"}}}}
    ns: "error-handler"```
````

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the error took place because the tool could not connect to the MySQL server. The  ECONNREFUSED error message states that the server rejected the connection request.

Possibly, the reasons were incorrect server settings, incorrect login details, or configuration errors.

Please check the below options:

- Ensure that the MySQL server is active, and the IP address 127.0.0.1:3306 is available.
- Make sure that your login details for connection to the MySQL server are correct.
- Check the MySQL server settings and make sure that it allows external connections.
- Check the SqlTools extension configuration and make sure that you have specified the correct MySQL server address, provided the correct login details, and set other settings correctly.